# Sql Server Installation Code error

Tags: sql-server

My problem is this, I want to Install Sql server 2014 in my Pc but i have a problem with it:

SQL Server Setup failure.

SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

The SQL Server license agreement cannot be located for the selected edition, SQLBI. This could be a result of corrupted media or the edition being unsupported by the media.

Error code 0x858C001B.

My pc is new, I have not had any previous version of SQL server on this pc.. Do you have a Solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks DavidG, I´m going to try (y)